# Как задать параметру CSS бесконечное значение?

Tags: javascript, css, tampermonkey

Я юзерскриптом добавляю в таблицу стилей новый стиль, который по сути заменяет старый, но с иными параметрами. По факту мне нужно удалить у предыдущей таблицы 3 параметра, но если я добавляю новую таблицу просто без них, то они перенимают значение из дефолтной таблицы.
Если я задаю значение, то эти значения перезаписываю стандартные. Но значения меня не устраивают, мне нужно что бы они были динамичными, то есть максимально возможными для каждого элемента.

Как мне задать такое значение? Или как удалить эти параметры с помощью новой таблицы с тем же именем класса?

```js
const style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML = `
  .product-snippet_ProductSnippet__name__mdters {
        display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-line-clamp: max ; <--
        vertical-align: middle;
        height:max ; <--
        max-height: max ; <---
        overflow: hidden;
      }
    `;
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То есть нужно сделать 100 процентов контейнера? импортант позволит переопределить родительское свойство селектора

```
-webkit-line-clamp: 100% !important;
 vertical-align: middle;
 height:100% !important;
 max-height: 100% !important;
```

[!important](http://htmlbook.ru/index.php/css/%21important)

Comment: Да, оно самое! Хватило просто указания 100%, без !important;(но полезная штука, буду знать). Благодарю!

Comment: @user15993460 тогда отметьте как ответ галочкой)

Comment: Конечно! Искал, но не совсем очевидно)